# How do I style an e-mail hyperlink to display using Razor in ASP.Net MVC3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, email, razor, hyperlink

HTML `<a href="mailto:name@dmain.com"> name@dmain.com </a>` works as normal in an MVC 3 View  - except that the display is invisible - white text on a white background and if I mouse over it I see the e-mail address that's "displayed" isn't underlined.

So, I tried adapting George's answer at [MailTo link in Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250494/mailto-link-in-razor) to

```
`@helper EmailTextBox(string email, string title) {
    <a href="mailto:@email">@title</a>    
    }
```

and

`@EmailTextBox("name@domain.com", "name@domain.com")` (both in a view)

and this also works - also generates an e-mail message with the e-mail address pre-populated like a normal HTML e-mail hyperlink - except that the display is still invisible - white text on a white background and if I mouse over it I see it also isn't underlined.

Applying a style to the containing  tag doesn't work.

So, how can I apply a style to get the e-mail address to display (or is there perhaps some other method)?

Comment: I have to believe this is a CSS issue. Have you checked `a:link`, `a:visited`, `a:hover` and `a:active`?  Have you looked at it with Firebug?

Comment: Sorry - Robert - Only noticed your reply now.

YES - Both you and David were correct. As I've mentioned in reply to David, I'd commented out the standard default anchor styles since they had seemed to overide my navigation styles initially - but restoring them hasn't overridden the nav styles now and the e-mail link displays normally again.

Sorry to waste your time with something so trivial, but I was unable to style the e-mail link alone to force it to display.

Thanks 4 ur time and help!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a css issue, try seeing what styles are applied to this tag (right click -> inspect element in Chrome, Firefox with the firebug extension, etc.)

You can always override the style being applied with something like

```
<style>
  a {
    color : black !important;
  }
</style>
```

But it would be much better to find out what rule is causing the color in the first place.

---

## EDIT

I have not worked with the razor view engine in MVC, always keep in mind that this is emitting html, anything you can do in html should be achivable. Make good use of Firebug or equivalent to view what html you are generating.

I would be very surprised if you could not do

```
`@helper EmailTextBox(string email, string title) {
    <a class="email" href="mailto:@email">@title</a>    
    }
```

then

```
 <style>
   a.email {color:black;}
 </style>
```

But it really sounds like you should make the rule turning links white much more narrow.

Comment: Thanx DavidYes, I've since realised that the styles that make the navigation White (because of being on a blue tabbed background) are somehow affecting anything that has any linking property, including e-mail links and normal hyperlinks within pages (although the styles are supposed to be limited to only nav elents - and are outside of the MVC world).

Comment: I don't have a problem creating styles, (as you have suggested in your reply) - in fact the whole navigation system is just CSS - my problem is applying styles to MVC @ Helpers.

Comment: Sorry - Keep reflexivly using ENTER for a new line and submitting! ;-)

I'm aware of adding styles via @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "nosubMVC" }) - although that doesn't seem to actually work?

Definitely doesn't seem to be usable to style the e-mail link? Is there perhaps some other way of applying a specific style just to a specific MVC  @ Helper, David?

Thanx 4 ur helpfulness.

Comment: I'd commented out the default anchor style, since that initially seemed to be overiding the navigation styles - but restoring them restored the display and the navigation styles seem to have survived OK. Just other issues now that I'm checking in another browser type! But at least the e-mail link is displaying. Sorry to have wasted your time with something so trivial.