# Add mailto link to actionlink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

How can i add a mailto link to a MVC Html.Actionlink Helper?

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @{ var email = "mailto:" + item.user.Firstname + "@testmail.org";}
            @Html.ActionLink(item.user.Fullname, email)

        </td>
```

only creates a link that looks like this in my browser:
http://localhost:53371/Open/mailto%3amail%40testmail.org

Comment: possible duplicate of [MailTo link in Razor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250494/mailto-link-in-razor)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't want to use `Html.ActionLink` here as you aren't specifying a route for it go to, i.e. a Controller or Action.

Try this instead:

```
@{ var email = "mailto:" + item.user.Firstname + "@testmail.org";}
<a href="@email">@item.user.Firstname</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.

Do you really have to use @Html.ActionLink ? Just use standard html anchor tag